# Unable to lazy reverse when using django-localeurl

Tags: python, django, django-localeurl

I'm using djangio-localeurl to provide locale switching based on my URLs. It works fine pretty much apart from a little hiccup.

In some of my class-based views, I have been using a lazy reverse function else I get errors about missing URL patterns. This was something due to the order in which files were imported. One explanation read:

> Since the decorators of your views are evaluated during parsing
>   urls.py you have an 'chicken - egg' problem. The method reverse()
>   can't be used since urls.py is not read.

It seems that django-localeurl monkey-patches Django's internal `reverse` function. This change works fine but my `lazy_reverse` function gives me issues. Now when I run my tests, I get errors at the places where I've used this `lazy_reverse` function. Here's my `lazy_reverse` function code:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.core import urlresolvers

reverse_lazy = lambda name=None, *args : lazy(urlresolvers.reverse, str)(name, args=args)
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError: Lazy object returned unexpected type.
```

I can seem to understand what is causing this. This issue seems to disappear the moment I remove `localeurl` from my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an error in lazy_reverse function it seems. I've not modified my `lazy_reverse` function to return `unicode` instead of `str`. Here's what it looks like:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

reverse_lazy = lazy(reverse, unicode)
```